# Ubuntu installation problem (Secure boot)

Tags: system-installation, secure-boot

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 to a new Acer Aspire E 14 using a bootable pen drive. When I select the ubuntu os iso file from multisystem the PC shows this error:

```
error:Secure Boot forbids laoding module from 
(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loopback.mod.
error: no server is specified.
unaligned pointer 0x6653bd9aeb947c2c
Aborted. Press any key to exit._
```

[image: screenshot]

I have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode and Windows does not appear even in the grub menu. WiFi is not working either.

Comment: When I switch from secure boot to legacy mode I able to install Ubuntu. But problem is when I in legacy boot mode the pc only find Ubuntu and when secure mode it find only window. And the grub option does not appear. What can I do?

Comment: @MeganFoxz, that question and answer is so broad and unclear to me. I also use `sudo update-grub` inside Ubuntu but it can't find windows, but windows exist.

Comment: Do not try to mix BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode and EFI/UEFI-mode OS installations; instead, [disable the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) and install Ubuntu in EFI mode. I also don't recommend trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a new (purchased in 2017, or even 2016) computer; instead, try Ubuntu 16.04.2 or 17.04, which are the latest as I write. New computers often have new hardware that's not supported in older releases, so you should use the latest Ubuntu version available.

Comment: Although this looks like a duplicate, the referenced question is from the early days of Secure Boot in Ubuntu (2013); support is much better today. Thus, I suspect the cause and *optimum* solution may be different, although it's possible that disabling Secure Boot would work for this case as well as the stated duplicate. The mixed-mode install may be the cause of the secondary problem of Windows not appearing in the GRUB menu; or that may be the result of filesystem damage, as in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914895/im-afraid-that-i-broke-my-partitions-on-my-computer/)

Answer (score 2):

If your windows is installed under UEFI, you will have to install Ubuntu under UEFI too to make dual boot work.

To get over the boot problem, you will have to disable Secure Boot in UEFI setup .. in what in the old days was called bios-setup .. not disable UEFI itself.

Comment: Thank you. I want to disable secure boot but I couldn't reach the option, this button is disabled. Pointer not able to enter the option.

Comment: I disable secure boot and install Ubuntu again and restart. But only windows appear and no grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Its says you need to go into your bios and disable/ turn off secure boot option

plz tell me more , you want to put the Ubuntu iso on a usb and install a persistent install to the hard drive ? of your  Acer Aspire E 14? are you trying to milti boot or single os ? 
are you working with a windows machine rn or Ubuntu. 
did disabling secure boot work ?

Comment: Don't post comments as answers !